# What is Logsource for Aspnetcore.Authentication.JwtBearer

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, serilog, asp.net-core-security

I have aspnetcore2 api that is using `IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer` packes to handle access token authentication.

I've setup Serilog logging in my application with the following config:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .MinimumLevel.Information()
    .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)
    .MinimumLevel.Override("System", LogEventLevel.Warning)
    .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication", LogEventLevel.Warning)
    .WriteTo.Logger(l => l.MinimumLevel.Verbose().WriteTo.Console())
    .WriteTo.Logger(l => l.MinimumLevel.Information().WriteTo.File("logs/logfile.log",
        rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day, retainedFileCountLimit: 10))
    .CreateLogger();
```

I was able to Override log levels for `System` and `Microsoft` log sources.

However I still receive the following log entry in my log file:

```
2018-05-23 20:30:27.228 -04:00 [INF] AuthenticationScheme: Bearer was successfully authenticated.
```

I can't seem to figureout the log source for `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer` so I can filter them out like I did `System` and `Microsoft`.

Comment: Yes, I was able to trace the logger. Since I'm using `IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation` they implement their own `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`. So the log source ended up being `IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation.IdentityServerAuthenticationHandler`

Comment: Simply adding `.MinimumLevel.Override("IdentityServer4", LogEventLevel.Warning)` also works

Comment: Are log sources linked to the assembly?  I'm running into this and trying to filter out those pesky MSFT logs